# Access custom object in ListCellRenderer JAVA

Tags: java, jlist, renderer

I have custom object that includes specific image URL & name. And I have ListCellRenderer class to show image and text. I want to ask how can I access the custom object's image URL in ListCellRenderer class ?
My ListCellRenderer class:

```
class CustomCellRenderer extends JLabel implements  ListCellRenderer    
{
 private    ImageIcon   image;

public CustomCellRenderer()
{
    setOpaque(true);

    // I want to use list item's image url to get image here
    image = new ImageIcon( "img/mark.png" );
}

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, Object value, int index, 
        boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus ) 
{
    // Display the text for this item
    setText(value.toString());
    // Set the correct image
    setIcon( image );
    // Draw the correct colors and font
    //      if( isSelected )
    //      {
    //          // Set the color and font for a selected item
    //          setBackground( Color.red );
    //          setForeground( Color.white );
    //      }
    //      else
    //      {
    //          // Set the color and font for an unselected item
    //          setBackground( Color.white );
    //          setForeground( Color.black );
    //      }

    return this;
}
}
```